# Newly added db tables on PostgreSQL are getting dropped and re-created during Strapi v4 startup when running on a blue-green deploy on AWS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, strapi, blue-green-deployment

We’re having a bizarre database issue using Strapi V4 (Node.js API framework)… Newly added PostgreSQL DB tables are getting dropped and re-created during startup ONLY when running on a blue-green deployment on AWS.

We’d appreciate help from anyone who has specific experience with this kind of situation using this framework or could lend us a senior/DevOps engineer for an hour or two to get a pair of fresh eyes on the problem.

We’re unable to reproduce this in local dev environments or cloud environments that use in-place deployment, so it’s been extremely troublesome trying to figure out the exact cause. (We can’t switch prod to in-place deploys because of uptime SLA with our clients.)